# Use XSLT to merge a collection of XML files and filter data

Tags: xml, xslt, localization, merge, filtering

I have a collection of many XML files that I have to import in a tool, which unfortunately cannot import several files at a time. So I need to merge them all in one final file.

These are three abrigded sample files I would need to merge (all three are identical except for the Spanish text in input file 3):

**Input file 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16LE"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx
SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4">
<header o-tmf="Euramis" creationtool="tm3" creationtoolversion="8.20 from 29-08-2011 15:47" segtype="sentence" datatype="PlainText" adminlang="EN-US" srclang="EN-GB">
</header>
<body>
<tu>
<prop type="Txt::Doc. No.">22004D0069</prop>
<tuv lang="EN-GB">
<seg>Text in English: blabla</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv lang="DE-DE">
<seg>Text in German: blabla</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv lang="ES-ES">
<seg>Text in Spanish: blabla</seg>
</tuv>
</tu>
</body>
</tmx>
```

**Input file 2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16LE"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx
SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4">
<header o-tmf="Euramis" creationtool="tm3" creationtoolversion="8.20 from 29-08-2011 15:47" segtype="sentence" datatype="PlainText" adminlang="EN-US" srclang="EN-GB">
</header>
<body>
<tu>
<prop type="Txt::Doc. No.">22004D0070</prop>
<tuv lang="EN-GB">
<seg>Text in English: blabla</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv lang="DE-DE">
<seg>Text in German: blabla</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv lang="ES-ES">
<seg>Text in Spanish: blabla</seg>
</tuv>
</tu>
</body>
</tmx>
```

**Input file 3:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16LE"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx
SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4">
<header o-tmf="Euramis" creationtool="tm3" creationtoolversion="8.20 from 29-08-2011 15:47" segtype="sentence" datatype="PlainText" adminlang="EN-US" srclang="EN-GB">
</header>
<body>
<tu>
<prop type="Txt::Doc. No.">22004D0068</prop>
<tuv lang="EN-GB">
<seg>Text in English: blabla</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv lang="DE-DE">
<seg>Text in German: blabla</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv lang="ES-ES">
<seg>Blablabla: a different text in Spanish</seg>
</tuv>
</tu>
</body>
</tmx>
```

And this is what I want to achieve:

**Expected output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tmx xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl">
   <body>
      <tu>
         <prop type="Txt::Doc. No.">22004D0068</prop>
         <tuv lang="EN-GB">
            <seg>Text in English: blabla</seg>
         </tuv>
         <tuv lang="ES-ES">
            <seg>Blablabla: a different text in Spanish</seg>
         </tuv>
      </tu>
      <tu>
         <prop type="Txt::Doc. No.">22004D0069</prop>
         <tuv lang="EN-GB">
            <seg>Text in English: blabla</seg>
         </tuv>
         <tuv lang="ES-ES">
            <seg>Text in Spanish: blabla</seg>
         </tuv>
      </tu>
   </body>
</tmx>
```

Therefore, the transformation implies:

- Getting rid of any language what is not EN-GB or ES-ES
- If two or more tu items have the same EN-GB tuv/seg content, only keep the ones with distinct ES-ES content. That is why tu 22004D0068 and tu 22004D0069 should be kept, but tu 22004D0070 should not (its ES-ES is a duplicate of 22004D0069).

I have managed to write a stylesheet that *merges* all files, but does not remove undesired tuv items (i.e. DE-DE) and does not filter out the whole tu item with EN-GB and ES-ES tuv/seg content that is already in another tu.

This is my stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="collection">
        <xsl:copy-of select="collection('input_dir?strip-space=yes;select=*.tmx')/*"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="tu" select="distinct-values($collection/tmx/body/tu/tuv)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <tmx>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="$tu">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="($collection/tmx/body/tu[tuv[@lang='EN-GB']=current()])"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </tmx>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is what it does:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tmx xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl">
   <body>
      <tu>
         <prop type="Txt::Doc. No.">22004D0068</prop>
         <tuv lang="EN-GB">
            <seg>Text in English: blabla</seg>
         </tuv>
         <tuv lang="DE-DE"> <!-- German language should be left out -->
            <seg>Text in German: blabla</seg>
         </tuv>
         <tuv lang="ES-ES">
            <seg>Blablabla: a different text in Spanish</seg>
         </tuv>
      </tu>
      <tu>
         <prop type="Txt::Doc. No.">22004D0069</prop>
         <tuv lang="EN-GB">
            <seg>Text in English: blabla</seg>
         </tuv>
         <tuv lang="DE-DE"> <!-- German language should be left out -->
            <seg>Text in German: blabla</seg>
         </tuv>
         <tuv lang="ES-ES">
            <seg>Text in Spanish: blabla</seg>
         </tuv>
      </tu>
      <tu> <!-- this whole tu item should not be in my output -->
         <prop type="Txt::Doc. No.">22004D0070</prop>
         <tuv lang="EN-GB">
            <seg>Text in English: blabla</seg>
         </tuv>
         <tuv lang="DE-DE">
            <seg>Text in German: blabla</seg>
         </tuv>
         <tuv lang="ES-ES">
            <seg>Text in Spanish: blabla</seg>
         </tuv>
      </tu>
   </body>
</tmx>
```

I think I'm half-way through, but I'm stuck and need some help. Could someone give me a hint or point me in the right direction? I have very basic knowledge of XLST, as you can see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XSLT way of thinking takes some getting used to.

I see you find all the distinct values first, which is fine. But then this line should be fixed:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="($collection/tmx/body/tu[tuv[@lang='EN-GB']=current()])"/>
```

The line above applies templates (processes the input) to **all** tu elements that have one of the distinct values. I understand you only want to process one tu element there per one distinct value. But which one? Does it matter? You can try with the first one by adding another predicate there: `position()=1` or `[1]` for short.

Comment: Thank you so much, Miro. This helps, but still I don't get the results I need. I need to get rid of all `<tuv lang='DE-DE'>` elements (or any other potential language which is not EN-GB or ES-ES). And I think something is missing in my specification of "distinc value": not only `<tuv lang="EN-GB">` but also  `<tuv lang="ES-ES">` should be considered as well. The text in these two `tuv` elements needs to be the same for two `tu` elements to be considered duplicates.

Comment: Getting rid of `<tuv lang='DE-DE'>` - add a template:    `<xsl:template match="tuv[@lang='DE-DE']"/>` or make a default template for all `tuv` elements `<xsl:template match="tuv"/>` and another one for the ones you want to keep `<xsl:template match="tuv[@lang='EN-GB' or @lang='ES-ES']"> <xsl:copy-of> ...`  I'm not sure how you want to consider the distinct values between different languages. Do you want select `tu` elements with distinct values in the `tuv` elements?

Comment: Thank you, Miro! I have managed to get rid of the unwanted languages. 

Regarding the distinct values, I'm trying with something like `distinct-values($collection/tmx/body/tu[concat(tuv[@lang='EN-GB'],'++',tuv[@lang='ES-ES']) != concat(preceding-sibling::tuv[@lang='EN-GB'],'++',preceding-sibling::tuv[@lang='ES-ES'])]/tuv)` or `distinct-values($collection/tmx/body/tu[tuv[@lang='EN-GB'] != preceding-sibling/tuv[@lang='EN-GB'] and tuv[@lang='ES-ES'] != preceding-sibling/tuv[@lang='ES-ES']]/tuv)` but it seems I add more elements rather than leaving only unique `tu` ones.

Comment: To illustrate the distinct-value requirement, please consider the following examples, where the first letter is the `<tuv lang='EN-GB'>` element and the second letter is the `<tuv lang='ES-ES'>` element within one same `tu` element: A-B is distinct, C-D is distinct too, A-B is a duplicate so we want to get rid of it, C-D is a duplicate too, but A-F is distinct despite repeating A because both letters need to be different from other items, E-F is distinct despite repeating F... And so on.

Comment: Hi Miro. If you update your answer with what you were saying in the comment I can vote it up as the most useful ansewr. I could manage to do everything I wanted except one thing.